# Finding the highest value in a column for a given range in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm quite new to pandas and dataframes. I want to find the product ('product') from a dataframe that gave the highest income ('income') in the years ('year') 1990 to 1999.

My best attempt only gives me the row number from the dataframe and the income, although I want it to show all other columns as well.

This was my best attempt:

```
HighestIncome90s = df.head(1)
HighestIncome90s = df.loc[(df['year'] >= 1990) & (df['year'] <= 1999), 'income'].nlargest()
```

Comment: it would be nice if you gave a sample from dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try fixed your code with `sort_values`

```
df = df.sort_values('income',ascending=False)

HighestIncome90s = df
HighestIncome90s = df.loc[(df['year'] >= 1990) & (df['year'] <= 1999), 'income'].head(1)
```

If you would like get all column

```
Allcol = df.loc[(df['year'] >= 1990) & (df['year'] <= 1999),].head(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to show all other columns as well.

If you use
[`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html),
as in

```
max_income_idx = df.income[(df['year'] >= 1990) & (df['year'] <= 1999)].idxmax()
```

then it will be the index of the largest relevant income. You can then use it with `df.loc[max_income_idx, :]` to get all columns for that.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, your source DataFrame contains income data for
each product and year, something like:

```
    year product  income
0   1980      P1  120.15
1   1990      P1  120.15
2   1992      P1  140.20
3   1994      P1  160.51
4   1996      P1  171.04
5   1988      P2  140.17
6   1991      P2  145.17
7   1993      P2  160.42
8   1995      P2  181.73
9   1989      P3  140.17
10  1992      P3  175.17
11  1994      P3  240.42
12  1996      P3  315.73
```

But you are interested only in rows for *year* between *1990* and *1999*.

Then, you want to sum the income for each product (for the whole 10 year period).
The code to do it is:

```
wrk = df.query('year.between(1990,1999)').groupby('product').income.sum()
```

For the time being, for the above source data, we have the following
*Series*:

```
product
P1    591.90
P2    487.32
P3    731.32
Name: income, dtype: float64
```

(the left column is the index and the right - total income for each
product).

And to get the final result (the "best-seller" product and the total income
that it brought) run:

```
result = wrk.sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)
```

It is also a *Series*, but containing only one element:

```
product
P3    731.32
Name: income, dtype: float64
```

(*P3* is the index and *731.32* is the total income).

All other solutions (presented so far) give the biggest income for
a **single year** (within the period of interest), not the **total**
income in this period.

Answer (score 0):

**First Step :** this code use to limit the year from 1990 to 1999

```
df = df.query('year >= 1990 & age <= 1999')
```

**Second Step :** after that use this code to sort income from the highest value

```
df = df.sort_values('income', ascending=False)
```